# Vim folding breaks colorscheme

Tags: vim

Sometimes, my colorscheme gets messed up by folds, as in the image. Is there any way to prevent this? The fold method here is indent, I don't recall, whether this happens with other fold methods.

[image]

Opening the last correctly colored fold fixes the next one, but not further, so to fix the whole document, I basically have to open all folds and scroll to the bottom.

I don't think there are any parts of my .vimrc that could cause this (maybe except a julia support plugin).

Comment: "I don't think", "maybe"… how about removing all that uncertainty? Disable that plugin, try Vim with the default config (`$ vim --clean`), etc.

Comment: It doesn't happen with enough consistency. I wouldn't be able to tell, if was the cause, or if it just worked this time.

Comment: What happens if you `<C-L>` or `:e %` in this situation? Does it fix it?

Comment: @AndR you are right, it is duplicate, didn't find that one. Also Friedrich yeah, <C-L> does fix it when that happens. Thanks!